# Is the complement of a vertex figure in an (abstract) polytope connected?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, discrete-mathematics

I consider an (abstract) regular polytope $P$, and $H$ a vertex figure of $P$. Is the complement $P \setminus H$ connected (as a poset, in the sense that its Hasse diagram, ignoring the improper faces, is connected)? I think it is necessary to require that the Schlafly numbers are finite.